# Subdomain folder content returns 404, but root level works

Tags: dns, subdomain, apache2, ubuntu, vhost

I am setting up a subdomain - `subdomain.example.com` for my existing `example.com` to serve application with distinct origin

Using DNS manager of my registrar, DNS Manager:
type `CNAME`, name: `subdomain`, points to `@`

And in my Apache 2.4 sites-available I have the existing `example.com.conf`and `example.com-ssl.conf`
so I made a new vhost for my subdomain, `subdomain.example.com.conf` and `subdomain.example.com-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/subdomain/public_html"
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/subdomain/public_html>
           AllowOverride All
           Order Allow,Deny
           Allow from All
        </Directory>
        LogLevel trace5
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Server Folders:

```
/var/www/subdomain/public_html
/var/www/subdomain/public_html/icons
```

If I browse to subdomain URL, it works fine:
`http://subdomain.example.com`
**works**

Now if I browse to any subdirectory content, it returns 404:
`http://subdomain.example.com/icons/icon.png`

**Not Found**
The requested URL was not found on this server.

subdomain-error.log error:
`AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/share/apache2/icons/icon.png`

What am I doing wrong? Or there is an something else causing this?

Comment: Do you have any `Alias` directives for `/icons` anywhere in your Apache configuration?

Comment: Are there any errors in other error.log files?

Comment: I went through the other conf files too, there is no "icons" mentioned in the "sites-available" directory
no errors under these settings in the subdomain-error.log file

Comment: How are you testing that URL?   Are you using `curl`?   If you are using your web browser have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Does the hit to `icon.png` show up in `subdomain-access.log`?

Comment: Access Log: [15/Sep/2021:13:54:56 +0200] "GET /icons/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 5150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
cURL:
... <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>

Comment: Does that mean it is logged in access.log  and not subdomain-access.log?

Comment: I meant subdomain-access.log just wrote it quickly, sorry

Comment: Somehow the subdomain-error.log wasn't active, now I can see an error:
[Wed Sep 15 21:05:58.815994 2021] [core:info] [pid 11901] [client 156.205.244.210:20449] AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/share/apache2/icons/icon.png
So the path used is "/usr/share/apache2/" and not "/var/www/subdomain/"

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: running on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in a default configuration file that is included with Apache2 from Debian and Ubuntu: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf` which has:

```
# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If
# you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
```

You can comment out that line in the configuration, or delete the sym-link to that configuration file so that Apache doesn't use it: `sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf`. After making configuration changes, you need to tell Apache to reload all its configuration:  `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Another option is to choose a different directory name for the icons on your own site. You might want to choose a different name, because edited configuration files could get reverted to the original when upgrading Apache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I thought It was a problem in my config or setup

Comment: I initially thought it sounded like an `Alias` problem.   I should have had you do a `grep -r 'Alias.*icon' /etc/apache2` when I asked if you had any such directives.